# RETURN NEXT in Postgres Function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, set-returning-functions

I'm currently writing a plpgsql function that will select from a table and produce a substantial amount of data.

I was originally going to return an array, but I found a resource that explains the "[RETURN NEXT](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html) operation - Very handy for callers.

However, I read this blurb which is concerning:

> Note: The current implementation of RETURN NEXT and RETURN QUERY stores the entire result set before returning from the function, as discussed above. That means that if a PL/pgSQL function produces a very large result set, performance might be poor:

Is there a Postgres feature that would allow my function to **stream** the results back to the caller as they're produced? This might be a limitation of Postgres' architecture in general, but I want to make sure I'm not overlooking something!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the results are not meant to be used in a subquery but by code, you may use a [`REFCURSOR`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpgsql-cursors.html) in a transaction.

Example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION example_cursor() RETURNS refcursor AS $$
DECLARE
  c refcursor;
BEGIN
  c:='mycursorname';
  OPEN c FOR select * from generate_series(1,100000);
  return c;                                       
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Usage for the caller:

```
BEGIN;
SELECT example_cursor();
 [output: mycursor]
FETCH 10 FROM mycursor;

 Output:

 generate_series 
-----------------
               1
               2
               3
               4
               5
               6
               7
               8
               9
              10

CLOSE mycursor;
END;
```

When not interested in piecemeal retrieval, `FETCH ALL FROM cursorname` may also be used to stream all results to the caller in one step.

Comment: Is it just me, btw, or is the inability to use `FETCH` in PL/PgSQL or in a subquery a very frustrating limitation?

Comment: @Craig: it can't be used in subqueries but constructs like `FOR vars in FETCH 10 FROM mycursor LOOP` or `RETURN QUERY FETCH...` are allowed in plpgsql.

Comment: Thanks for the input - I did come across REFCURSOR, but was hoping for something I could use in a sub expression as well. This will suffice for now.